# Progress Bar for API ajax request starts loading only after getting response from API

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, api

I'm using this jsFuddle http://jsfiddle.net/GvdSy/ for implementing progress bar. But the problem is that bar starts loading only after I get response from API not when I create a request for API.
How can I start loading the progress bar as soon as I Start initiating the API call(click on button) and make it to 100% only after I get a response from API i.e. Progress bar should be consistent with the whole duration.

This is the code I used:

```
$.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "Post",
            data: "",
            async: true,
            url: "/Apps/AddConnector?connectorId=" + connectorId + "&consumer=" + consumer,
            xhr: function () {
                var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                console.log(percentComplete);
                progressBar.css({
                    width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                });
            }
                }, false);
                return xhr;
            },
            success: function (Response) {
               if (Response.Status == "Success") {
                    try { mixpanel.track('Application', { 'App Id': connectorId }, { 'Action': 'added' }); } catch (ex) { }
                    try { ga('send', 'event', 'Applications', connectorId, 'apps_added'); } catch (ex) { }
                    progressLabel.text("Installed");
                }
                else {
                    progressLabel.text(Response.Message);
                    setTimeout(function(){flipInstance.slideToggle("slow");},2000);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, e) {
                if (!HandleAjaxError(xhr, e, "")) {
                    progressLabel.text(e);
                }
           },
        });
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? For me in Chrome the example in your fiddle makes steady progress as it loads, which I assume is the intended behaviour.

Comment: I'm using chrome..for fiddle it's working properly but for me it's showing only "1"

Comment: So you have to be aware that the progress is based upon data received, if 0 out of 100000 data has come in, that is what will show in the progress bar.

var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total; 

This is what the bar visibility is based on.

Comment: You could technically start the progress bar at like 5% before evt.lengthComputable becomes truthy, this will give you a visual that the load is starting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "Post",
            data: "",
            async: true,
            url: "/Apps/AddConnector?connectorId=" + connectorId + "&consumer=" + consumer,
            xhr: function () {
                var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable && evt.loaded) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                console.log(percentComplete);
                progressBar.css({
                    width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                });
// HERE IS WHERE YOU IMPLEMENT AN ELSE, BEFORE evt.lengthComputable is truthy
                } else {
                    progressBar.css({
                        width: '2%'
                    });
                }
                    }, false);
                    return xhr;
                },
                success: function (Response) {
                   if (Response.Status == "Success") {
                        try { mixpanel.track('Application', { 'App Id': connectorId }, { 'Action': 'added' }); } catch (ex) { }
                        try { ga('send', 'event', 'Applications', connectorId, 'apps_added'); } catch (ex) { }
                        progressLabel.text("Installed");
                    }
                    else {
                        progressLabel.text(Response.Message);
                        setTimeout(function(){flipInstance.slideToggle("slow");},2000);
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, e) {
                    if (!HandleAjaxError(xhr, e, "")) {
                        progressLabel.text(e);
                    }
               },
            });
```

Comment: it's not hitting the else part

Comment: change your if statement to this 
if (evt.lengthComputable && evt.loaded) {

Comment: That means both (evt.lengthComputable && evt.loaded) are truthy, which means you are receiving data nearly instantly. Your next step is finding out at what threshold of percentComplete, you want it to move down to the else statement.

You'd do that by doing 
if (evt.lengthComputable && ((evt.loaded / evt.total) > 0.05)).

Comment: but evt.loaded is coming always 1